# Android - Dynamically created View's unexplained top margin

Tags: android

The idea is to create TextViews for programs in nice little 200x200 squares in the shape of your favourite tetris squares. These views then move on to their own course relevant to themselves.

Problem im facing is this:
  [image]

The first two views have this step difference from the top that comes from nowhere. Need to align them side by side instead.
I've checked their margins when debugging, and it was the same, as well as the layout they are in and well, the code below.

Relevant code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // within each tablerow, we then create the tablecolumns
            // assuming we want two columns only. Change 2 otherwise.
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                try {
                    TextView nyan = new TextView(this);
                    nyan.setText(pail.get(count).getProgramName());
                    nyan.setClickable(true);
                    nyan.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, 200));
                    nyan.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    //nyan.setPadding(10, 50, 10, 50);
                    nyan.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.programlistback);
                    nyan.setSingleLine(false);
                    nyan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                                    CourseList.class);
                            i.putExtra("selectedProgram", pail.get(count)
                                    .getProgramID());
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });

                    tr.addView(nyan);
                    // when done with textview creation, update tick for nyan
                    count++;
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    Log.i("expect", "tableOrigin - hit " + count + "th index");
                }
            }
            tabLayout.addView(tr, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```